# Designing Application for Android(Photoshop)

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, mobile, screen-resolution

I am designing(**PSD**) an Application for Android OS, which will be developed by developer. I need to provide him the mockup of Design(**PSD**), Which we target to run on all android devices. I have searched for resolution to design, but the answer I have seen is really large number of resolutions.

Do I need to design Application for every device separately. or Is there any standard sizes I could design, So that I work on all devices?.

Can anyone explain here with the Resolution and PPI.

Comment: Have you seen this yet http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?

Comment: `the answer I have seen is really large number of resolutions` **correct**. `Do I need to design Application for every device separately.` **yes** - at least, design at 480, 320, 240 and 160 dpi. `Can anyone explain here with the Resolution and PPI.` **too broad** - search on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could design it for many screen sizes. Note that today most devices are widescreen. So the first step should design a 16:9 layout. You have to design it vertically and horizontally way.

So, at this point you should think about two layouts at first: Horizontal and vertical. You should now start to imagine the look of the app in both alignments. Second, you should note if the app will be for tablets, for smartphones or both. So, in case you have to design for both, then now you have to think in 4 layouts: Tablet horizontal, Tablet Vertical, Smartphone Horizontal, Smartphone Vertical.

Now? Take your Photoshop and start to design. You can download many Android PSD Templates for mocking up your layouts. Which resolutions to choose? Well, I'd go for 1200x675 for Smartphones and 1920x1080 for tablets.

Note that this is for having a reference for the developer. If he needs Pixel Perfect layouts then you should talk closely with him.

Answer (score 0):

ldi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi :: 0.75x:1x:1.5x:2x
 So make each of the drawables (png) with resolution in that ratio